# I'm trying to implement a messenger chat plugin in the js file, but I have a confusion on how to integrate it

Tags: reactjs

```
this is the messenger chat plugin code which is I got from facebook page. I want to 
implement this code in react js file.
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
  xfbml            : true,
  version          : 'v6.0'
});
};

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-customerchat"
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="your_page_id"
  theme_color="#20cef5">
</div>
```

this script I want to implement in the react js file anyone please can help me:)
because I'm unable to implement it in react js file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unofficial package, or look how it's implemented and take what you need.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-messenger-customer-chat

```
<MessengerCustomerChat
  pageId="<PAGE_ID>"
  appId="<APP_ID>"
  htmlRef="<REF_STRING>"
/>
```

`ref` is a topic that will help you understand what's going on.
Happy coding

Answer (score -1):

Copy following script in `public/index.html` file in head section

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
  xfbml            : true,
  version          : 'v6.0'
});
};

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Put `<div id="fb-root"></div>` in `return()` of App.js

Use following code in the component of your choice. (Use `className` instead `class`).

```
const MyComponent = () => (
<div className="fb-customerchat"
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="your_page_id"
  theme_color="#20cef5">
</div>
)
```